# How to use a default layout while keeping the route definitions in their respective eager-loaded module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, eager-loading

I have the some routes defined in the `AppRoutingModule` and they use a default layout -

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

Now I want to add an eager-loaded feature module, `AuthModule`, with the following routes -

```js
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
```

I want `RegisterComponent` and `LoginComponent` to use the default layout, and for that I need to define these two new routes in the `AppRoutingModule` like -

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
            { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

But I don't want to move these routes in `AppRoutingModule`. I want them contained in their respective routing module, the `AuthRoutingModule` and still use the default layout. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `loadChildren` property and return the module directly in the callback function.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DefaultLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
            { path: '', loadChildren: () => AuthModule }  // <---
        ],   
    }
];
```

Comment: I thought of `loadChildren()` too. But isn't it supposed to be used for loading lazy child routes? `AuthModule` is not lazy, it is imported directly in `AppModule`. Also, there's an issue with the way you are using `loadChildren()` - `children` and `loadChildren()` both cannot be used with a route definition.

Comment: You are totally right about the `children` +` loadChildren`. You can overcome that using a _componentless_ route ( I've edited the answer to show you an example). And yes, the loadChildren is used to lazy-load modules using the `import` statement but the callback can also return a module directly and the module would be included in the main chunk.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've checked that this works fine without importing `AuthModule` in the `AppModule`'s imports array, and `AuthModule` is still eager loaded.